# Insert data into local database using ado.net in a console application

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is what I have written so far.There is no exception so I am assuming the connection is working fine but no data is inserted into the database table. Please tell me what is wrong with my code

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyETL.Properties.Settings.connectionStr"].ConnectionString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                // foreach (student stu in stulist)
                // {
                string strQuery = "INSERT INTO Student(Sid,st_name) VALUES (@id,@name)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "111");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "nallia");


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {

                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: where are you calling this ??

Comment: why is conn.close in catch, it should be in finally

Comment: or may be you do have an exception but just ignoring it..

Comment: try to change the `catch(Exception ex){throw ex;}` like this

Comment: Those were just random changes I made looking fora solution. I did like   catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
               
            }

Comment: but still no exception ...then why doesnt it work

Comment: Try to change Query like This `"INSERT INTO Student(Sid,st_name) VALUES (" + "@id,@name)"`

Comment: @ Webruster I did still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 static void Insert()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyETL.Properties.Settings.connectionStr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn =new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student(Sid,st_name) VALUES (" +
                       "@id,@name)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 111);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "nallia");


                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //Log exception
            //Display Error message
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it still doesnt add any record into the table. When I  ran it in debug mode value of rows was 1 and it throw an exception. Do you think my connection is ok with the database?

Comment: I do see the connected sign like of a switch with the database in the server explorer but still no data is getting inserted...what to do??

Comment: I restarted my visual studio and deleted and made a new database but its still doesnt work

Comment: @aneena Try turning `@Name` into `@name`. Same for `@id`. Are the database fields text and number types, respectively?

Comment: @aneena check your db connection , By Test connection. is it showing suceed ? after that as Victor said the field same should be same as db column Names

Answer (score 0):

It has been nearly 2,5 years but if you haven't still solved this problem, you should change the "copy to output directory" attribute to "copy if newer". Your database is changing but every time you start debugging, you read the initial version of database so, you see that there is no changes.