# Saving an Api response to the database. (JSON ARRAY)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am currently working on a project. I am really bad at coding so I need the help. In Visual Studio, I have a form where it can retrieve an external API. After retrieving an API, it will display in a response box.

I have a separate button when clicked, will allow certain specified data to be saved to the database (Table name devicedata)

Technologies used: Visual Studio, Microsoft SQL server

Any and all help that can be rendered is much appreciated

*at the same time, please advice on how I can get better with coding. I feel that there are too many things to learn is such a short amount of time

I have successfully completed the string display function via a tutorial. Im currently stuck on saving the returned data to the database

```
private void btnGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RestClient rClient = new RestClient();
    rClient.endpoint = txtRestURI.Text;
    rClient.authType = authenticationType.Basic;
    rClient.authTech = authenticationTechnique.RollYourOwn;
    rClient.userName = txtUserName.Text;
    rClient.userPassword = txtPassWord.Text;

    debugOutput("Rest Client Created");

    string strResponse = string.Empty;

    strResponse = rClient.makeRequest();

    debugOutput(strResponse);
}

private void debugOutput(string strDebugText)
{
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(strDebugText + Environment.NewLine);
        txtResponse.Text = txtResponse.Text + strDebugText + Environment.NewLine;
        txtResponse.SelectionStart = txtResponse.TextLength;
        txtResponse.ScrollToCaret();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message, ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

This code above successfully returns the details of the API after using the external WEB API link as shown below:

"data": [{ 
"device": "51REF2", 
"date": 2359, 
"datas": "9999584adfasfr" 
}]

the details in the API are dummy data

## And after the details are returned, i would like the information in the  "device", "time" and "data" fields to be saved to the database

This code below is a function that I wrote halfway but couldn't complete due to lack of knowledge.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString;
    SqlConnection cnn;
    string txtResponse;
    connectionString = @"Data Source=(Server name);Initial Catalog=DemoDb;User ID=John;Password=1234";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    String sql = "";
    sql = "Insert into devicedata";
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Open  !");
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: you want to store json in database or  read json and insert into table? Update your question with table structure in which you want to insert

Comment: @RamAnugandula hi. i may have made some mistakes with the question. The response that i am getting back seems to be in the form of a String and not a JSON object. My apologies. i will change the title of the question as requested

Comment: update question with your api response and table structure you want ot insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json string is not in valid format you should have provided with dummy data. But I assume it as json object and deserialized your json string to object.

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{        
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into devicedata(device,time,date) VALUES (@device,@time,@name)", con))
     {
          con.Open()
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device", jsonObj.data.device);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", jsonObj.data.time);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", jsonObj.data.name);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
     }
}
```

Comment: The API gets retrieved in a JSON array. Dummy data of the array is as shown below. "data": [
        {
            "device": "51REF2",
            "time": 268795471,
            "data": "9999584adfasfr",
            "rolloverCounter": 0,
            "seqNumber": 8569,
            "rinfos": ""

Comment: At the same time, i will re-edit my question in the original post

Comment: Note that `data` is an array in OP's JSON, and OP has now asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140540/newtonsoft-json-linq-jarray-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-device) about this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can refer to this one

```
using (SqlConnection conn =new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student(Sid,st_name) VALUES (" +
                       "@id,@name)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 111);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "nallia");


                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }
            }
```

[Insert data into local database using ado.net in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998508/insert-data-into-local-database-using-ado-net-in-a-console-application)

and you might want to review some sql queries about insert

https://www.dofactory.com/sql/insert